# click to element in iframe run function in document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to this

```
<span id="name-test" class="editable">test</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.editable').click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'))
 });
</script>
```

but inside iframe like this

```
<iframe src="source" id="iframe">
 {{-- This is content of source --}}
 <span id="name-test" class="editable">test</span>
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.editable').click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'))
  });
</script>
```

any idea if it's possible? 
Thanks

Comment: Is iframe src pointing to a local site or some external site?

Comment: Side note; `$(this).attr('id')` is an anti-pattern anyway, as the `id` is already exposed as a property on the Element.  `this.id` works fine.

Comment: iframe code can't accest parent window elements....

Comment: `$('.editable').click` - there's no `.editable` when this runs as the iframe won't have loaded yet.  At the minimum, add it inside doc.ready, the iframe load event or use event delegation.

Comment: @MisterJojo isn't it the other way around?  parent code accessing iframe element

Comment: @freedomn-m no, it's both

Comment: i want to get know if element with class inside iframe is clicked by anything.